# Case insensitive headers in Nginx Lua

Tags: nginx, lua

Is there a way we can get case insensitive header response from Nginx Lua?

for example I want:

```
content_by_lua_block {
  ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = { 'aaaaaaaaa' }
  ngx.header["SEt-Cookie"] = { 'a123qwds' }
}
```

The response I get is always the last one. I want both cookies as they are different with case sensitivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) field names are case-insensitive, so both of those field names refer to the same field and the second reference overwrites the first one.

If you expect case-sensitive headers (not case-insensitive ones you currently get), then I don't think it's possible, at least not from a spec-compliant HTTP server. Note that **field values** are case-sensitive, but not field names.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to override HTTP server with Lua and do this?

Comment: I don't think so and I don't see a need to do this as you can return multiple cookies using the same table: `ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = { 'cookie1=abc', 'cookie2=def' }`.